# Configuring XC164CS for I2C Communication with 24LC16 EEPROM

Tags: i2c

I'm currently studying an old automotive ECU that has an `XC164CS-32F` microcontroller and a `24LC16` `I2C` EEPROM. The microcontroller [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-XC164CS_32-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a3043136c9a8b01136d9c9f930069) and user manuals ([UM1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/xc164_32_um_v1.0_2004_05_sys.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b40afa6906d4) / [UM2](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/xc164_32_um_v1.0_2004_05_sys.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b40b002806da)) do not mention support for the I2C protocol but the EEPROM is directly connected to the microcontroller's `PORT0` pins 68/69 (`P0L.1` and `P0L.2`).

Datasheet says that these pins are bidirectional I/O ports that can be configured as "external bus" communication lines. I wonder if it's possible to configure the external bus to interface with this I2C EEPROM, even though the microcontroller does not explicitly support I2C according to the documentation.

I know this is an archaic microcontroller but does anyone have experience with it? Is it even possible?

Pinout: https://imgur.com/a/e7afURH

PORT0 definition: https://imgur.com/a/OvkIUGT

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

Almost any IO pins on any MCU can be used to control the pins in any way you like in software.

As long as the software can control the hardware pins as inputs and outputs or bi-directional pins, the I2C protocol can be implemented in software. There is no need for the MCU hardware to support I2C protocol, as long as the IO pins can simulate the open-drain IO mode under software control.

And to simplify it even more, as the I2C EEPROM clock pin is an input only, the MCU can just always keep the clock pin as push-pull output. Only the data pin needs to be bi-directional.

Comment: `Almost any IO pins on any MCU can be used to control the pins in any way you like in software`

Yes but if there's no dedicated peripheral is there any other way other than bit-banging?

Comment: No, if there is no dedicated peripheral you must do the protocol yourself, in any method available for you to implement it. It could be software bit-banging by controlling the pins and delay loops, or it could be a timer interrupt based state machine or whatever, as long as the software tells the hardware to toggle the pins in a way that the memory chip understands as I2C protocol.

Comment: Sniffing it with a logic analyzer, I can see that the clock and data pins run at 200 kHz. Plus, given it's an automotive ECU, bit-banging sounds a little bit strange to me.

Comment: Well, it could use the synchronous serial communication interfaces to implement I2C, like USI on AVRs or SSP in PICs. But the P0L.1 and P0L.2 pins don't have that alternate functionality, only GPIO and address/data bus for external parallel memories.